# C# - I need to access a subkey in the registry, I can assess the parent key,

Tags: c#, permissions, registry

This is not an issue running the app as Administrator, it is running as Administrator, it is somehow an issue with permissions on a certain registry Key

I think I have worked out it is actually a permissions issue on the ProfileList registry key

In my code, I can access this key and return a list of all Sub-keys (including ProfileList)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

C# will not, for some reason, see this key at all, even though it is listed as a sub-key when I access the parent key in C#

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Does anyone please know a workaround . . .

Comment: Why do you expect it's a permission issue? Have you seen some difference in permission setting between `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`?

Comment: Also, as you are working with `HKLM` be aware of 32 / 64bit registry tree.